# How to use "OculusRiftEffect.js" on the "webgl_interactive_cubes" examples

Tags: three.js, webgl, oculus

I was very excited when I first saw this example ([webgl_geometry_minecraft_oculusrift](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_geometry_minecraft_oculusrift.html)) in [mrdoob/three.js · GitHub](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) website. Undoubtedly, it's pretty awesome!

But I'm curious, how to apply this effect on other examples? So I try to implement this effect in the "webgl_interactive_cubes". However, the experimental result is worse than expected.

My problem is that I can't accurately align the cursor to a particular cube to make it change color, seems to be a problem with the projection function? Then I adjusted the screen width coefficient, like this

> window.innerWidth * 2

in the whole program. But still can not improve this problem.

Summary my issue :

1. If I want to apply *Oculus Rift Effect* on **any example**, how should I do? by th way, I only added the following code

   ```
           effect = new THREE.OculusRiftEffect( renderer );
           effect.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

           // Right Oculus Parameters are yet to be determined
           effect.separation = 20;
           effect.distortion = 0.1;
           effect.fov = 110;
   ```

   in initialize block `init();` and final added `effect.render( scene, camera );` in `render();`
2. I am very curious to know how

   `var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouse.x, mouse.y, 1 );
   projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );`

   works. Why do need to pass parameter 1? what if I change `mouse.x` to `mouse.x * 2`
3. Need to use dual monitors can only be fully present this effect?

Note: My English is not very good, if I have described is unclear, please ask your doubts, I will respond as soon as possible.

This is my DEMO link:

1. http://goo.gl/VCKyP
2. http://goo.gl/xuIhr
3. http://goo.gl/WjqC0

My Folder : https://googledrive.com/host/0B7yrjtQvNRwoYVQtMUc4M1ZZakk/

Comment: Can you share a link to the tweaked webgl_interactive_cubes?

Comment: I have to make up link URL in the bottom of the article

Answer (score 0):

The third one is your example right?

This can help you to use the OR-Effect in a easier way:
https://github.com/carstenschwede/RiftThree

And your examples work all, just the third one have to Problem with the Controls. If I drag the move from the Stats-DIV (FPS) It works.